# what is the best way to combine two numpy matrix row by row?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two numpy 2D matrix i and u

```
import numpy as np
u = np.array([[1,2,3],[3,4,5]])
i = np.random.rand(3,4)
u
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [3, 4, 5]])
i
array([[0.01564089, 0.01274327, 0.39282509, 0.25177788],
       [0.08531619, 0.04668083, 0.91260452, 0.63481191],
       [0.34607795, 0.87053449, 0.27467456, 0.02215169]])
```

And I want to combine two matrix row by row like follows

```
array([[1,2,3, 0.01564089, 0.01274327, 0.39282509, 0.25177788],
[1,2,3, 0.08531619, 0.04668083, 0.91260452, 0.63481191],
[1,2,3, 0.34607795, 0.87053449, 0.27467456, 0.02215169],
[3,4,5, 0.01564089, 0.01274327, 0.39282509, 0.25177788],
[3,4,5, 0.08531619, 0.04668083, 0.91260452, 0.63481191],
[3,4,5, 0.34607795, 0.87053449, 0.27467456, 0.02215169]]
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way using `numpy.repeat` and `numpy.tile`:

```
def join(arr1, arr2):
    a1 = np.repeat(arr1, arr2.shape[0], 0)
    a2 = np.tile(arr2, (arr1.shape[0], 1))
    return np.hstack([a1, a2])
join(u, i)
```

Output:

```
array([[1.   , 2.   , 3.   , 0.832, 0.885, 0.86 , 0.233],
       [1.   , 2.   , 3.   , 0.76 , 0.46 , 0.421, 0.654],
       [1.   , 2.   , 3.   , 0.083, 0.   , 0.981, 0.047],
       [3.   , 4.   , 5.   , 0.832, 0.885, 0.86 , 0.233],
       [3.   , 4.   , 5.   , 0.76 , 0.46 , 0.421, 0.654],
       [3.   , 4.   , 5.   , 0.083, 0.   , 0.981, 0.047]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this with `itertools.product`

```
import itertools  
ls=[np.concatenate([x,y]).tolist() for x,y in itertools.product(u, i)]
combinedarray=np.array(ls)
combinedarray
```

Output:

```
u
[[1 2 3]
 [3 4 5]]

i
[[0.99154112 0.72960938 0.5764647  0.34136825]
 [0.6014229  0.81085954 0.00631983 0.15401643]
 [0.98828194 0.46407222 0.60403416 0.20934805]]

combinedarray
array([[1.     , 2.     , 3.     , 0.99154112, 0.72960938, 0.5764647, 0.34136825],
       [1.     , 2.     , 3.     , 0.6014229 , 0.81085954, 0.00631983, 0.15401643],
       [1.     , 2.     , 3.     , 0.98828194, 0.46407222, 0.60403416, 0.20934805],
       [3.     , 4.     , 5.     , 0.99154112, 0.72960938, 0.5764647, 0.34136825],
       [3.     , 4.     , 5.     , 0.6014229 , 0.81085954, 0.00631983, 0.15401643],
       [3.     , 4.     , 5.     , 0.98828194, 0.46407222, 0.60403416, 0.20934805]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your arrays (changing `i` to ints just to make the display more compact):

```
In [230]: u = np.array([[1,2,3],[3,4,5]]) 
     ...: i = np.random.randint(0,10,(3,4))*10                                                       
In [231]: u                                                                                          
Out[231]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [3, 4, 5]])
In [232]: i                                                                                          
Out[232]: 
array([[40, 20, 40, 10],
       [20, 10, 90, 50],
       [50, 10, 10, 30]])
```

Make a target array - 3d:

```
In [233]: res1 = np.zeros((2,3,7))
```

Change the (2,3) `u` to (2,1,3), and let broadcasting expand it to (2,3,3):

```
In [234]: res1[:,:,:3]=u[:,None,:]
```

Then broadcast the (3,4) `i` to (2,3,4) slot

```
In [235]: res1[:,:,3:]=i[None,:,:]       # None is optional here                                                            
In [236]: res1                                                                                       
Out[236]: 
array([[[ 1.,  2.,  3., 40., 20., 40., 10.],
        [ 1.,  2.,  3., 20., 10., 90., 50.],
        [ 1.,  2.,  3., 50., 10., 10., 30.]],

       [[ 3.,  4.,  5., 40., 20., 40., 10.],
        [ 3.,  4.,  5., 20., 10., 90., 50.],
        [ 3.,  4.,  5., 50., 10., 10., 30.]]])
```

then reshape to (6,7):

```
In [237]: res1.reshape(-1,7)                                                                         
Out[237]: 
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3., 40., 20., 40., 10.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3., 20., 10., 90., 50.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3., 50., 10., 10., 30.],
       [ 3.,  4.,  5., 40., 20., 40., 10.],
       [ 3.,  4.,  5., 20., 10., 90., 50.],
       [ 3.,  4.,  5., 50., 10., 10., 30.]])
```

All values have to be int or float.  (Object dtype would allow a mix, but math on such an array is slower).

I can't say which approach is fastest.  One may be best for small examples like this (my bet's on the itertools), and another (mine?) for large cases.